# Java Constructor Overloading

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I'm new with Java and I'm having trouble understanding the constructor issue,
I have looked at many tutorials and still I'm having difficult to understand why we use constructors, anyway, my specific question is :

Correct me if I'm wrong, if i want to add in my class more than one constructor, I'll write the first one and the second will be `int` type (inside the brackets).

1. is it because the constructors have to be with the same name as the class and we need to distinguish between them ?
2. what if I want to add a third constructor ? Can it also be `int` type ?

Comment: If you don't understand why constructors are used, you might want to read on object-oriented programming first.

Comment: It’s correct, that you start with the first one and then write the second one, but everything else is nonsense. There is no requirement for the second to have/be an `int` type, hence, there is no problem having more than two constructors.

Comment: some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 4):

> a) is it because the constructors have to be with the same name as the
>   class and we need to distinguish between them ?

Yes constructors are always the name of the class without any return type, and in order to distinguish between them, you can have different parameters.

> b) what if i want to add a third constructor ? it can be also int type
>   ?

Yes, you can add any no. of overloaded constructors but those all should be different in no. and/or type of parameters.

Like :-

```
public User() // default constructor
{
}

public User(int age) // overloaded constructor with int
{
}

public User(String name) // // overloaded constructor with String
{
}

public User(String name, int age) // // overloaded constructor with String and int
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes a constructor has the same name as the `Class`.

As long as the constructors have different signatures you can have as many as you want.  The signature is what distinguishes one constructor from another...

```
public MyClass()
{
}

public MyClass(int a)
{
}

public MyClass(int a, int b)
{
}

public MyClass(String a)
{
}

public MyClass(int a, String b)
{
}
```

Those are all different because they have different signatures.

Comment: Signatures can be in the same type ?

Comment: @Yuvi1 I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: i see that the third constructor you wrote was with a String signature , it can be with int signature like the second one ?

Comment: Yes 2 constructors can have one parameter only called `a` as long as the type is different this makes the signature different so it is ok. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: is it ok that the first constructor will be MyClass(int a) and the second one will be MyClass(int b) ?

Comment: @Yuvi1 if you already have a constructor which uses a single `int` as its argument, you cannot create another constructor with matching parameters. The point of constructor overloading is to provide multiple ways of creating an object. What you name the parameter (`a` vs `b`) doesn't affect those rules.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you want to have 10000 constructor, you can as long a signature are differents.

```
public class People {
    public People(String name, int age) {
        ...
    }
    public People(String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can construct your object in a different way.
You can see an example by yourself looking at : [the java String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#constructor.summary) wich has a plenty of constructors.

And yes, all constructors have the same name of his class.

But this will not works :

```
public class People {
    public People(String name, int age) {
        ...
    }
    public People(String name, int numberOfLegs) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since you have two constructors with the same signature

Comment: Instead of telling what an IDE might show, you can directly point to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#constructor.summary

Comment: It would appear that javac is happy with 500,000 constructors, but gets a bit unhappy at something between 500,000 and 18,844,174 constructors, though that could just have been the memory limitations of my machine

Comment: you really tryied it?

Answer (score 1):

The constructors purpouse is to contain the code to inizialize the object. Usually, the initialization is done using constructor parameters. You can have different constructors with different parameters list, as needed by your context. It is a good pratice to do *constructor chaining*, that is calling a base constructor from others.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the @brso05 answer,

This is also one of the ways:

```
public MyClass( int a)
{
}

public MyClass( int a, int b)
{
}

public MyClass( int a, String b)
{
}
```

And So on..It is the arguments which make difference, rest remains the same!